# How to make .addAction do something

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

This may have been asked before but I'm still not sure of what to do. I am new to android studio and creating an app in general thus all terms seems foreign to me. Not sure where to go when I click snooze or when I click stop. Should I make a function for the snooze? If so, how do I tie it back to the addAction function?

```
PendingIntent main = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, Homepage.class),0 );

NotificationCompat.Builder notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("Hello alarm")
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round, "Snooze", main)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round, "Stop", main)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
```

Comment: please elaborate your question ...

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You have set the actions to call the `main` `PendingIntent`, what you miss to do is to actually build this notification and register it. From the official android documentation https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html
it remains to write:

```
// Sets an ID for the notification
int mNotificationId = 001;
// Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Builds the notification and issues it.
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, notif.build());
```